# ¿A qué se debe el siguiente error?

Tags: php, mysql, webservice, xampp

```
id = $id; $this->nombre = $username; $this->password = $password; public function obtener_id() { return $this->id; } public function obtener_nombre() { return $this->nombre; } public function obtener_password() { return $this->password; } public function cambiar_password($password) { $this->password = $password; } } } ?>
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Usuario' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\Biblioteca\includes\RepositorioUsuario.inc.php:22 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Biblioteca\index.php(23): RepositorioUsuario::obtener_todos(Object(PDO)) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Biblioteca\includes\RepositorioUsuario.inc.php on line 22
```

**RepositorioUsuario.inc.php**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**usuario.inc.php**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El archivo `usuario.inc.php` no es válido ya que inicias con `<?`

Todo archivo de php debe iniciar con

```
<?php
```

Ademas de que no cerraste correctamente la función `__construct`